# How to read json file in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my asp.web api 2.0 project I have a Json file, where all the error codes are mapped. I want to read the json file in order to return response to the caller.

I am unable to read the same, however if I use console application following code works, any suggestion will be helpful.

Code that works in console application:

```
 var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 using (var stream = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp24.Utilities.StatusCodes.json") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
 {
     var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());    
 }
```

Using above code provides assembly as null in web api project, hence I changed it to following:

```
var assembly = GetWebEntryAssembly();
using (var stream = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PaymentAccount.Api.Resources.StatusCodes.json") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
{
     var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());       
}

private Assembly GetWebEntryAssembly()
{
     if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null ||
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance == null)
     {
           return null;
     }

     var type = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType();
     while (type != null && type.Namespace == "ASP")
     {
           type = type.BaseType;
     }

     return type == null ? null : type.Assembly;
}
```

The exception I get is:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Server.MapPath` it is easy for ASP.NET to find your files but the file still have to be inside of the application root folder, here is some official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8) on this function.

Just place file inside your root folder, and then use `Server.MapPath` this will allow your ASP.NET application to find your file in the Server file system.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/files/myfile.json"));
```

Comment: I was able to solve it using Server.MapPath, even though I kept the file in different folder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this :**

```
    public object Get()
{
    string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\data.json");

    object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

**this code returns json text**